# AngularJS Directive and Isolate Scope

Tags: service, angularjs, scope, directive

I am trying to understand how to pass data through my directive so that I can bind it at the view level. I believe I understand the separation of controller scope vs. the directive isolate scope but I cant seem to get a simple json result out to my view. My JSFiddle can be found here http://jsfiddle.net/jamesamuir/2KLVj/4/.

```
app.directive('testList', function (testService) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',

        link: function ($scope, element, attrs) {

            $scope.name = 'isolate scope';
            $scope.data = {};
            $scope.data.loadtext = testService.getJSON().then(function (data) {
                alert(data);
                element.addClass("red");

            });
        }
    }
});
```

It seems to me that this should work but, alas, it does not. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside your `then()` callback, assign `data` to `data.loadtext`:

```
testService.getJSON().then(function (data) {
   alert(data);
   element.addClass("red");
   scope.data.loadtext = data;
});
```

<kbd>[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mrajcok/x6Cbu/)</kbd>

Comment: Since `return`ing from a promise creates a new promise with that value, and the AngularJS view system can bind to promises, adding `return data;` at the end of the `then` callback will also work (since there is an assignment on the call to `then`). That said, I believe setting the data explicitly and not creating a new promise is better.